# Android superuser shutdown/reboot commands not doing anything

Tags: android, runtime.exec, su

I am trying to make an app that can shutdown/reboot your phone at the touch of a button. I found a command online for reboot:

```
public void rebootPhone() {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reboot");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I understand this requires root (for the "su" superuser command); My phone has been rooted so I can gain su access. However when this method is run (after I press 'yes' on the prompt to allow su access) the phone does not reboot, nothing happens! Is there something else i need to include to make the phone reboot?

Also, what is the su command for shutdown (i.e. to just turn your phone off)? I can't find it anywhere on the net.

Comment: What's wrong with holding down the power button to get the reboot menu?

Comment: nothing! this app is purely for convenience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "su" in one process and "reboot" in another expecting it to have super user status. The command "su -c reboot" might work for you though.

Comment: Might work.  Not all versions of su hacked to be usable support arguments, you may have to push the command to be executed into the stdin of the su-created shell.

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c reboot");` worked thanks :) would you happen to know the shutdown command? I've tried `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c shutdown");` it does nothing...

Comment: @Keiron Gulrajani I'm afraid I don't know of a standard Android command to shut the device down.

Comment: is there any possibility to use that without "su" ?

Comment: @Sathish I haven't looked at Android in years so I don't know what is current, but I would hope not as this would make it far too easily for a malicious application to create a denial-of-service attack.